# Фильтр для списка из бинарных данных

Tags: erlang

Следующий код

```
-module(dec).
-compile([export_all]).
packet(<<_Num:32/unsigned-little-integer, Bin/binary>>) ->
    lists:reverse(lists:foldl(fun parse/2, [<<>>], [<<C:8>> || <<C:8>> <= Bin])).

parse(<<0:1, C:7>>, [Cur|Acc]) ->
    [<<0:1, Cur/binary, C:7>> | Acc];
parse(<<1:1, C:7>>, [Cur|Acc]) ->
    [<<>>, (<<0:1, Cur/binary, C:7>>) | Acc].
```

позволяет сделать первоначальную обработку сообщения

```
3> Bin = <<195,191,0,0,192,129,2,127,195,35,101,98,28,127,97,2,232,128,132,177,194,36, 
3>   104,34,199,128,128,38,191,12,245,128,128,128,254,0,84,96,103,17,224,16,231, 
3>   128,50,60,58,206,128,128,128,128,128,128,2,76,113,203,128,177,185,36,104,34, 
3>   199,128,128,38,191,12,246,128,128,128,251,28,43,99,60,128,128,128,50,60,58, 
3>   206,128,128,128,128,128,128,2,76,113,203,128,177,247,36,104,34,199,128,128, 
3>   38,191,12,247,128,128,128,128,174,128,50,60,58,206,137,128,128,128,128,128,2, 
3>   76,113,203,128,177,195,36,104,34,199,128,128,38,191,12,248,128,128,128,128, 
3>   34,120,147,128,50,60,58,206,128,128,128,128,128,128,2,76,113,203,128>>.
<<195,191,0,0,192,129,2,127,195,35,101,98,28,127,97,2,232,
  128,132,177,194,36,104,34,199,128,128,38,191,...>>
4> dec:packet(Bin).
[<<"@">>,
 <<1>>,
 <<0,191,195>>,
 <<0,71,151,17,207,248,65,104>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<4>>,
 <<"1">>,<<"B">>,
 <<4,154,17,71>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<19,63>>,
 <<6,117>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<"~">>,
 <<0,5,76,25,200,224>>,
 <<"\bg">>,
 <<0>>,
 <<6,79,29,78>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0>>,
 <<0,...>>,
 <<...>>|...]
```

Есть ли возможность добавить фильтр, который бы оставлял, например, каждый
5 и 6 бинарь и далее с шагом 7?

Answer (score 1):

```
[<<C:8>> || <<C:8>> <= Bin]
```

Это означает, что перед тем как сделать фильтрацию, вы сперва разбиваете весь исходный бинарник в список где каждый байт -- элемент списка. Это должно быть чертовски неэкономно по памяти. Прям совсем. Ибо список не будет вычисляться лениво, он будет вычислен сразу.

Лучше проходить исходный бинарь как есть, и брать лишь первый байт на каждой итерации, а остальное отдавать дальше. Выкинуть lists:reverse(lists:foldl и просто реализовать parse который проходит весь бинарник и складывает всё в список.

Как-нибудь так:

```
parse(Binary) -> parse(Binary, <<>>, []).

parse(<<>>, _Curr, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
parse(<<0:1, C:7, Rest/binary>>, Curr, Acc) ->
  parse(Rest, <<0:1, Curr/binary, C:7>>, Acc);
parse(<<1:1, C:7, Rest/binary>>, Curr, Acc) ->
  parse(Rest, <<>>, [<<0:1, Curr/binary, C:7>> | Acc]).
```

> 5 и 6 бинарь и далее с шагом 7?

Не совсем понял про шаг, но вообще вы можете подсунуть какой-нибудь счётчик в аргументы, и увеличивать его на каждой итерации.

Например так:

```
parse(Binary) -> parse(Binary, <<>>, 0, []).

parse(<<>>, _Curr, _Counter, Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
parse(<<0:1, C:7, Rest/binary>>, Curr, Counter, Acc) ->
  parse(Rest, <<0:1, Curr/binary, C:7>>, Counter, Acc);
parse(<<1:1, C:7, Rest/binary>>, _Curr, Counter, Acc) when (Counter rem 6) == 0 ->
  parse(Rest, <<>>, 0, Acc); % just ignore collected Curr
parse(<<1:1, C:7, Rest/binary>>, Curr, Counter, Acc) ->
  parse(Rest, <<>>, Counter+1, [<<0:1, Curr/binary, C:7>> | Acc]).
```